# Can you find lost Nodes in the Node Editor?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, interface, compositing-nodes

Just for fun I moved the Nodes in the *Compositing* tab by a freaking high x-Value and y-Value and in two Groups. Now I can't recover it!

When I press <kbd>A</kbd> (to select everything) and then <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> It shows that their value is infinite. I tried using the three auto recovers that Blender always makes in hopes of it being an older version so I can restore it. No success..

I tried to move it back with the negative value that I originally set, but I cant figure out the value (And it doesn't seem to move when I press <kbd>S</kbd> to see their position! [An arrow points at the Nodes]!

I tried copy pasting, I tried to turn it into to a group, but you cant put Render Layer0. I tried to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find specific Nodes. I tried to press the <kbd>.</kbd> on the Numpad to go there but Blender always crashed, just like with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> thingy.

Now I cant access to my nodes in the *Node Editor* again, I cant change them etc. I just need to connect the last node to the "Composite" Node and then everything is done. The Only thing I know is that the Mix Node has 2 Keyframes at the beginning of the Animation, so it's the so called "fade". I also tried selecting everything and then pressing <kbd>F</kbd>, but then a whitescreen just appears.

Does anybody know how I can set the Location of them to 0 or how I can connect the last node to the *Composite* node?? Please, you would tremendously help me, because I do not want to reexperience the hours of work that I put into this!

EDIT: I don't know how to program in Python, so please if someone can, help would greatly be appreciated!

And before you try, make sure to press <kbd>A</kbd> so everything is selected!

The file: http://www.mediafire.com/file/pcw2gcdcufpd9qv/Template+by+Khovinc+and+Torulus.blend

Comment: with all the nodes selected press `NumPad .` (period)

Comment: Please use proper spacing and paragraphs, your wall of text is very hard to read

Answer (score 7):

If Blender crashes while centering the Node editor on the selected node then they are indeed moved to infinity and it's some sort of a bug so at least compositing might be better to be redone.

Still there's a way to move one node from somewhere you don't see to another one you can actially see with [snapping in the Node Editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/node_editor/introduction.html#further-menus) (just like in 3d viewport) with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and then choosing element to snap to.

With the node somewhere far away selected, choose *Snap To X/Y* to snap selected node to any border of the node to snap to. Then press <kbd>G</kbd> to move selected node and hover mouse over the node which is seen in the editor.

[image: gif-of-dark-node-editor-magic]

With this way the node from somewhere away will be moved to the current 2d viewport position.

It's also possible to select all the nodes, press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale and enter `0` to move them all to the same place (like written in your question), but the pivot point will be somewhere between the selected nodes so that's where they will be moved to (actually it might be not really important). Hence after scaling with nodes still selected press <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> (period) and you should see the nodes in the center of the editor.